# Hadoop 5-Node Test Setup - Minimum Hardware Requirements

Tags: hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform, minimum-requirements

I am trying to find the minimum hardware requirements for a 5-node Hadoop (v 2.2) cluster that I will be setting for experimentation purposes.

Being as this cluster is being set up as only a test, I do not require massively powerful systems (I'm hoping to use beige boxes with only the minimum required hardware to create the environment). I've looked extensively online for hardware requirements but haven't found an answer for my specific needs.

The cluster will be I/O focused with its main purpose being to store and retrieve data (the file sizes will not be overly large).

I need minimum hardware specs for:

- NameNode
- YARN server (for resource management)
- DataNodes

As I am very new to Hadoop I may have left out some details that may be required to answer my question. Please advise if there is any other information I can provide.

Thanks in advance!